# concatenating to EOF in flex

Tags: flex-lexer, eof

I have the following line:

```
<INITIAL><<EOF>>        {return 0;}
```

and I need to ignore the last EOL - `\n` or `\r\n` before the EOF.
I can't figure out how to concatenate it to EOFso that it will be a valid regular expression.. I've tried:

```
<INITIAL>((\n)|(\r\n))*<<EOF>>      {return 0;}
```

but it says it's an "unrecognized rule".

Comment: Does the error message *actually* say that? If not, please quote it verbatim.

Comment: @EJP: I'm pretty sure that's what flex would say. `<<EOF>>` is not a valid component of a pattern; it can only be a complete pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<<EOF>>` is not really a pattern symbol, since it cannot be part of a pattern. Logically, the EOF marker is not a character; the `<<EOF>>` pseudo-pattern is the only flex pattern which can be matched by an empty string.

There is no flex pattern symbol which represents end of input and thus it is not possible to express a pattern "followed by EOF".

So you need to work from a different perspective: detect a pattern which is *not* followed by EOF.

If a pattern is not followed by EOF, it must be followed by at least one character. That we can write using  the trailing context operator. Once we've matched those instances of the pattern, any remaining match for the pattern can only be used if that match *is* followed by EOF, because of the longest match rule:

```
\r?\n/(.|\n)  { /* A new line NOT followed by EOF */ }
\r?\n         { /* A new line followed by EOF */ }
```

We needed to use `.|\n` in the trailing context because `.` doesn't match `\n`. The parentheses are unnecessary because of the precedence of the trailing context operator.

Forcing the detection of trailing context after a newline will make interactive use of this scanner annoying, since if a newline token is returned by the first rule, it will not actually be returned until another line is read.

---

By the way, there is no need for

```
<INITIAL><<EOF>>        {return 0;}
```

That is the flex default behaviour on end-of-file, and you only need an `<<EOF>>` rule if you need to do something prior to returning 0.